# expected while in do/while loop in roulette game c++

Tags: c++, xcode

Thank you for taking the time to review this questions, the task is to write an roulette game for class. but in order for this to work and do and while loop has to be configured for the age and the bet.

I am recieving at the moment a expected while in do/while loop error, but i cannot manage to figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    bool error = true;
    string namn;
    int insatsen;
    int alder;
    int amount = 1000;
    int insats = 100;
    int insats2 = 300;
    int insats3 = 600;



while(error) {
    cout << "hej och välkommen till His roulette" << endl;
    cout << "vad är ditt namn?" << endl;
    cin >> namn;
    cout << "välkommen \n" << namn << endl;


    do{
        cout << "hur gammal är du?" << namn << endl;
        cin >> alder;

        if (alder >= 18) {
            cout <<"tack så mycket" << namn << endl;
            error = false;
            continue;
        }
        else{
            cout << "du är för ung för detta spel";
            error = true;
        }


        }


        do{
        while(error){

        cout << "Hur mycket vill du satsa?" << endl;
        cin >> insatsen;
        if (insatsen != insats && insatsen != insats2 && insatsen != insats3){

            cout << "Vänligen välj en korrekt insats\n";
            error = true;

        }
        else {
    cout << "tack för din insats\n";
    error = false;
    continue;


        }
        }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer to one of these [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Syntax of do while loop is `do {
   statement(s);
} while( condition );` that you are not following.

Comment: If you start a block with `do`, this block has to end with a `while` statement. Neither of your `do` blocks have final `while`.

Comment: your `do{` misses the `} while(...);` and you have a trailing `}` at the end.

Comment: As a side note, learn to indent your code properly or use auto-formatting tools (AStyle, clang-format). Your life will much easier.

Comment: no intendation goes hand in hand with this kind of errors. Only the last lines of code are a clear indication that there is something wrong...

Comment: Thank you guys alot for the answers and the feedback. I have formatted the code and once again reviewed the documentation for do/while. thank you for taking the time to answer @kiranBiradar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first do-while loop ends at the second do statement, so c++ expected a while. Your syntax:

```
do{...}
do{while(error){...}}
```

The required syntax is:

```
do{
  ...
} 
while( condition);
```